# Javascript - Incrementing static function variable simulation with closures?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

So it seems like there are no function static variables in Javascript. I am trying to increment a variable inside a function, but I do not want to do it like this:

```
function countMyself() {
    if ( typeof countMyself.counter == 'undefined' ) {
        // It has not... perform the initilization
        countMyself.counter = 0;
    }
}
```

I would like to do it with the closures, but I am having a really hard time to understand these.

Someone suggested this in another question:

```
var uniqueID = (function() {
   var id = 0;
   return function() { return id++; };
})();
```

But all it does when I alert uniqueID, is printing this line: return function() { return id++; };

So I would like to know how to increment a variable in a function without polluting the global scope.

Comment: BTW, what's wrong with the first implementation?

Comment: What you are after is what's known as "private members". The definitive article on the subject (in my opinion at least) is Douglas Crockford's [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Comment: The conditional in the first version could be a one-liner: `countMyself.counter = countMyself.counter || 0;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must actually *call* `uniqueID` - you can't just refer to is as if it were a variable:

```
> uniqueID
function () { return id++; }

> uniqueID()
0

> uniqueID()
1
```

Comment: Wow thanks, this made me understand how the closures work! Finally

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to uniqueID explicitly instead of returning it from the immediately-invoked lambda might make things clearer:

```
var uniqueId; //declare uniqueId in the outer scope

function initializeUniqueId(){
    var id=0;
    uniqueId = function(){
        return id++;
    }
}

initializeUniqueId();

console.log( uniqueId ); //what you are currently doing
console.log( uniqueId() }; //what you should be doing.
```

The advantages of the version with the `(function(){}())` compared to the one I just wrote are that the initializer function is anonymous and that you only need to write "uniqueId" once.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple see this code**
I want to increment the '_a' variable

in **ES6**

```
let a = () => {
  let _a = 1;
  return () => _a++;
}

let clo = a();
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(clo());
}
```

in **ES5**

```
var a = function() {
  var _a = 1;
  return function() {
    return _a++;
  }
}

var clo = a();
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(clo());
}
```